# View Controller losing property values after init - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, viewcontroller

My view controller is losing it's properties after being called. So BaseTransitionController has an (assign) int value which changes as people move around the app. I want to get that int value in another view controller, so I am initializing it in this one (ViewController B). Self.indexSelectedLogin is a property of ViewController B. But both the rootController.indexSelected and self.indexSelectedLogin turn out having a value of 0, when they should have a value of 1-5. Thanks

```
@interface BaseTransitionController : UIViewController
@property (assign) int indexSelected;
------------------------------------------------------------------
View Controller B
BaseTransitionController *rootController = [[BaseTransitionController alloc] init];
self.indexSelectedLogin = rootController.indexSelected;
```

Comment: It's probably because you create a totally new `BaseTransitionController` instead of referencing the existing instance.

Comment: @rmaddy What do you mean by existing instance? I used BaseTransitionController so I can have multiple classes inherit from it and get the same properties as UIViewController plus the indexSelected property.

Comment: You need to access the `indexSelected` of some existing `BaseTransitionController`, correct? One that already has some value for its `indexSelected` property. In the tiny bit of code you show in your question you create a new `BaseTransitionController` and get its unset `indexSelected` property.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to retain the old int value and pass into the new int variable like that below:-

```
@interface BaseTransitionController : UIViewController
@property (assign) int indexSelected;

//Assuming here indexSelected =5;
------------------------------------------------------------------
View Controller B
@property (nonatomic,strong) BaseTransitionController *rootController
//Now in this before alloc init just check the instance of BaseTransitionController 

//if instance exist then you will get the retain value
self.indexSelectedLogin = self.rootController.indexSelected;

if(!self.rootController)
{
self.rootController = [[BaseTransitionController alloc] init];
 }
```

So like that way you can hold the value and set the same in your class accordingly.